# Created a maven project with jersey archtype but fail to build due to missing jersery servlet library

Tags: eclipse, rest, maven, jersey

I m trying to create a maven project with the jersey archtype by following the tutorial below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skltzZH7i4w&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTZh5U8RbdXq0WaYvZBz2rbn&index=11

The maven project fails to build with a number of errors.  The root cause, I believe, is this one:

The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\XXXXXXXX.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-servlet\1.20-SNAPSHOT\jersey-servlet-1.20-SNAPSHOT.jar'

The jar doesn't exist, in fact the \jersey... folder is missing.  I am using eclipse, and have installed m2e.  What else do I need to bring the jersey dependent files onto the computer?

Comment: can you please share the stacktrace, as i feel you are not able to donwload those dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I repeated the same steps on my home computer and was able to get thru.  I suspect the root cause was network/firewall setting at my work.